# Public search facebook user by Non-exact name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to do a public search on all facebook users according to the name of the user, but i want the search not to be on the exact name. for exmaple if a user will search for 'John Ada' the result 'John Adam' will be retreived too.
After that the results need to be ordered by mutual_friend_count.

I manged to do this partly with the following FQL :

```
SELECT uid,name, pic_square, profile_url , mutual_friend_count FROM user WHERE contains("Name Surename")
order by mutual_friend_count desc
```

but it returns only exact names, and if the name was missing a letter like my earlier example the user was not retreived.

I tried to mess around with the Offset and Limit but with no success either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook search algorithms seem to be optimized to find full names. A partial name never seems to return as many results as a full name will. In my experience, Facebook knows how to expand names for common variants. A search for "John Adam" will return "John Adams", "Johnny Adams" and "John Addams"

The other battle you are fighting is the Facebook filtering algorithm. Facebook first finds all matches that meet your query, *then* filters them for visibility to your user.

You can try adding `AND NOT is_blocked` to your `WHERE` statement. This should filter out anything that isn't visible to you before the filtering algorithm.